# Mixing Lens operations with "original" operations

Tags: haskell

Is it reasonable to mix `Control.Lens` operations with the ones provided by the "standard library"?

Consider the following fragment using qualified `Data.Map` as `Map`:

```
getUniqueIdent :: String -> State (Map.Map String Int) (Maybe String)
getUniqueIdent typeName = do indices <- StM.get
                             let identifiers = Map.lookup typeName typeNameMap
                             let uniqueIndex = Map.lookup typeName indices
                             StM.modify $ over (at typeName) (fmap succ)
                             let uniqueIdent = (^?) <$> identifiers <*> 
                                                        (element <$> uniqueIndex)
                             return $ join uniqueIdent
```

For example, I do use both the `Map.lookup` and `Lens.at` and also the `(^?)` as a safe alternative for `(!!)`.

Should I just stick to lenses "everywhere" (at least in spatially local code)?

Comment: Please state the purpose of your code in the title, rather than your concern — see [ask]. As the question stands, it's unclear what the purpose of the code is, and therefore your question is rather [hypothetical](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1709/9357).

Comment: @200_success Thanks! I wonder about the purpose of the code though - would it really help to state it in the title if the question can be applied in broader sense; that is, mixing two different "approaches / libraries" based purely on convenience of the code author?

Comment: We prefer titles describing the code; otherwise half the site would be "Too many if statements?" and the other half would be "Please help speed up my code." You could try a hybrid title like "Indentation control function that inconsistently uses Lens operations".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't say there's anything like a proscription against doing so, but as a non-user of `lens` I can't say it *helps* me understand what's going on. I'm also not sure that your data structure is complex enough to warrant using `lens` in this case, functions out of `base` tend to produce a pretty concise solution on their own when properly deployed.

I haven't tested this, but I think it's equivalent.

```
import Control.Monad.State
import Data.Map
import Safe (atMay) -- "safe".Safe.atMay :: [a] -> Int -> Maybe a

getUniqueIdent :: String -> State (Map String Int) (Maybe String)
getUniqueIdent typeName =
  do indices <- get
     modify $ adjust succ typeName
     return $ do identifiers <- Data.Map.lookup typeName typeNameMap
                 uniqueIndex <- Data.Map.lookup typeName indices
                 identifiers `atMay` uniqueIndex
```

Comment: I like the `Safe` library thing, certainly more explicit than hacking away with `Lense`s. The code is almost equivalent, but `lookup` returns `Maybe a`, so `atMay` would need to lifted - I think.

Comment: The inner `do`-block is using the `Monad Maybe` instance though, so `identifiers :: [String]`, `uniqueIndex :: Int`, and `atMay` is effectively a monadic action as it returns `Maybe a`. The result gets wrapped in a `return` in the `Monad State` instance `do`-block, which is what gives you the right return type overall. I *think* it works as is, but my internal compiler (The Basically Brainy Haskell Compilation System, version 0.0.0-prealpha9627) has been known to be faulty.

Comment: ah, you actually bind the `lookup` call with `<-`; it should strip the `Maybe`, yes, my bad